# Formatting data displayed on Multiple Radialbars ApexChart

Tags: javascript, charts, apexcharts

I am attempting to use the Multiple RadialBars chart to show 3 percentages, along with the "Total" average percentage in the middle. Documentation for this chart can be found here: https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/radialbar-charts/multiple-radialbars/

My issue is with how the chart displays the "Total" value. I would like this value to go out two decimal places, but instead, it keeps the full floating point value. I've attached an image to elaborate.
[RadialBar Long Percentage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLWgu.png)

I know this problem can be fixed by using a formatter for the total, and simply using the .toFixed(2) method. However, I can't seem to figure out the formatter for this chart. Without using a formatter, the default behavior finds the average of all three percentages (as seen above). The documentation unfortunately does not elaborate on how to customize the formatter function.

```
var efficiencyOptions = {
    series: [],
    chart: {
        height: 350,
        type: 'radialBar',
    },
    plotOptions: {
        radialBar: {
            dataLabels: {
                name: {
                    show: true,
                    fontSize: '22px',
                },
                value: {
                    show: true,
                    fontSize: '16px',
                },
                total: {
                    show: true,
                    label: 'Total',
                    // formatter function goes here
                    formatter: function (w) {
                       // Need to find average of three percentages and fix to two decimal places
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    colors: ['#1ab7ea', '#0084ff', '#39539E'],
    labels: ["Laser 1", "Laser 2", "Laser 3"],
};
```

If anyone could help me figure out this formatter function it would be very appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score -1):

```js
value: {
                                formatter: function(val) {
                                    return parseInt(val);
                                },
                                color: '#111',
                                fontSize: '36px',
                                show: true
                            },
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)